# How to setup the Month for my date?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a weird bug regarding javascript date object

I have something like

```
 var year = 2014;
 var month = 11;
 var day = 29

 var date = new Date(year, month , day);
 console.log(date) -> give me Mon Dec 29 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) 

 var monthNum = date.getMonth();
 console.log(monthNum)  -> give me 11
```

If I change month to `12`, it gave me `Thu Jan 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`

I am not sure why the month is off by one. Can someone help me out about this? Thanks!

Comment: the indexing start from '0' not '1'. so it is from 0-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
var date = new Date(year, month , day);
```

to:

```
var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
```

This is because months in the JS date constructor begin at zero, i.e. 0 = Jan, 1 = Feb, ...

Answer (score 4):

Months in JavaScript date objects starts at 0. That means January is 0 while December is 11.

Answer (score 3):

The months argument in that constructor are 0-based, not 1-based.